# IE 11 is taking long time to load ng-option when dev tool is open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

The following code is taking long time in IE11 to load when developer tool is open. Without developer tool open the code is loading quickly.

I have reproduce this issue in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1266/).

Note: Open the developer tool first and open the fiddle link to reproduce.

Is there any solution to fix this problem?

**HTML**

```
 <select ng-options="o as o for o in timeArray" ng-model="selectedTime"></select>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.timeArray = ["12:00 AM","12:01 AM","12:02 AM","12:03 AM","12:04 AM","12:05 AM","12:06 AM","12:07 AM","12:08 AM","12:09 AM","12:10 AM","12:11 AM","12:12 AM","12:13 AM","12:14 AM","12:15 AM","12:16 AM","12:17 AM","12:18 AM","12:19 AM","12:20 AM","12:21 AM","12:22 AM","12:23 AM","12:24 AM","12:25 AM","12:26 AM","12:27 AM","12:28 AM","12:29 AM","12:30 AM","12:31 AM","12:32 AM","12:33 AM","12:34 AM","12:35 AM","12:36 AM","12:37 AM","12:38 AM","12:39 AM","12:40 AM","12:41 AM","12:42 AM","12:43 AM","12:44 AM","12:45 AM","12:46 AM","12:47 AM","12:48 AM","12:49 AM","12:50 AM","12:51 AM","12:52 AM","12:53 AM","12:54 AM","12:55 AM","12:56 AM","12:57 AM","12:58 AM","12:59 AM","1:00 AM","1:01 AM","1:02 AM","1:03 AM","1:04 AM","1:05 AM","1:06 AM","1:07 AM","1:08 AM","1:09 AM","1:10 AM","1:11 AM","1:12 AM","1:13 AM","1:14 AM","1:15 AM","1:16 AM","1:17 AM","1:18 AM","1:19 AM","1:20 AM","1:21 AM","1:22 AM","1:23 AM","1:24 AM","1:25 AM","1:26 AM","1:27 AM","1:28 AM","1:29 AM","1:30 AM","1:31 AM","1:32 AM","1:33 AM","1:34 AM","1:35 AM","1:36 AM","1:37 AM","1:38 AM","1:39 AM","1:40 AM","1:41 AM","1:42 AM","1:43 AM","1:44 AM","1:45 AM","1:46 AM","1:47 AM","1:48 AM","1:49 AM","1:50 AM","1:51 AM","1:52 AM","1:53 AM","1:54 AM","1:55 AM","1:56 AM","1:57 AM","1:58 AM","1:59 AM","2:00 AM","2:01 AM","2:02 AM","2:03 AM","2:04 AM","2:05 AM","2:06 AM","2:07 AM","2:08 AM","2:09 AM","2:10 AM","2:11 AM","2:12 AM","2:13 AM","2:14 AM","2:15 AM","2:16 AM","2:17 AM","2:18 AM","2:19 AM","2:20 AM","2:21 AM","2:22 AM","2:23 AM","2:24 AM","2:25 AM","2:26 AM","2:27 AM","2:28 AM","2:29 AM","2:30 AM","2:31 AM","2:32 AM","2:33 AM","2:34 AM","2:35 AM","2:36 AM","2:37 AM","2:38 AM","2:39 AM","2:40 AM","2:41 AM","2:42 AM","2:43 AM","2:44 AM","2:45 AM","2:46 AM","2:47 AM","2:48 AM","2:49 AM","2:50 AM","2:51 AM","2:52 AM","2:53 AM","2:54 AM","2:55 AM","2:56 AM","2:57 AM","2:58 AM","2:59 AM","3:00 AM","3:01 AM","3:02 AM","3:03 AM","3:04 AM","3:05 AM","3:06 AM","3:07 AM","3:08 AM","3:09 AM","3:10 AM","3:11 AM","3:12 AM","3:13 AM","3:14 AM","3:15 AM","3:16 AM","3:17 AM","3:18 AM","3:19 AM","3:20 AM","3:21 AM","3:22 AM","3:23 AM","3:24 AM","3:25 AM","3:26 AM","3:27 AM","3:28 AM","3:29 AM","3:30 AM","3:31 AM","3:32 AM","3:33 AM","3:34 AM","3:35 AM","3:36 AM","3:37 AM","3:38 AM","3:39 AM","3:40 AM","3:41 AM","3:42 AM","3:43 AM","3:44 AM","3:45 AM","3:46 AM","3:47 AM","3:48 AM","3:49 AM","3:50 AM","3:51 AM","3:52 AM","3:53 AM","3:54 AM","3:55 AM","3:56 AM","3:57 AM","3:58 AM","3:59 AM","4:00 AM","4:01 AM","4:02 AM","4:03 AM","4:04 AM","4:05 AM","4:06 AM","4:07 AM","4:08 AM","4:09 AM","4:10 AM","4:11 AM","4:12 AM","4:13 AM","4:14 AM","4:15 AM","4:16 AM","4:17 AM","4:18 AM","4:19 AM","4:20 AM","4:21 AM","4:22 AM","4:23 AM","4:24 AM","4:25 AM","4:26 AM","4:27 AM","4:28 AM","4:29 AM","4:30 AM","4:31 AM","4:32 AM","4:33 AM","4:34 AM","4:35 AM","4:36 AM","4:37 AM","4:38 AM","4:39 AM","4:40 AM","4:41 AM","4:42 AM","4:43 AM","4:44 AM","4:45 AM","4:46 AM","4:47 AM","4:48 AM","4:49 AM","4:50 AM","4:51 AM","4:52 AM","4:53 AM","4:54 AM","4:55 AM","4:56 AM","4:57 AM","4:58 AM","4:59 AM","5:00 AM","5:01 AM","5:02 AM","5:03 AM","5:04 AM","5:05 AM","5:06 AM","5:07 AM","5:08 AM","5:09 AM","5:10 AM","5:11 AM","5:12 AM","5:13 AM","5:14 AM","5:15 AM","5:16 AM","5:17 AM","5:18 AM","5:19 AM","5:20 AM","5:21 AM","5:22 AM","5:23 AM","5:24 AM","5:25 AM","5:26 AM","5:27 AM","5:28 AM","5:29 AM","5:30 AM","5:31 AM","5:32 AM","5:33 AM","5:34 AM","5:35 AM","5:36 AM","5:37 AM","5:38 AM","5:39 AM","5:40 AM","5:41 AM","5:42 AM","5:43 AM","5:44 AM","5:45 AM","5:46 AM","5:47 AM","5:48 AM","5:49 AM","5:50 AM","5:51 AM","5:52 AM","5:53 AM","5:54 AM","5:55 AM","5:56 AM","5:57 AM","5:58 AM","5:59 AM","6:00 AM","6:01 AM","6:02 AM","6:03 AM","6:04 AM","6:05 AM","6:06 AM","6:07 AM","6:08 AM","6:09 AM","6:10 AM","6:11 AM","6:12 AM","6:13 AM","6:14 AM","6:15 AM","6:16 AM","6:17 AM","6:18 AM","6:19 AM","6:20 AM","6:21 AM","6:22 AM","6:23 AM","6:24 AM","6:25 AM","6:26 AM","6:27 AM","6:28 AM","6:29 AM","6:30 AM","6:31 AM","6:32 AM","6:33 AM","6:34 AM","6:35 AM","6:36 AM","6:37 AM","6:38 AM","6:39 AM","6:40 AM","6:41 AM","6:42 AM","6:43 AM","6:44 AM","6:45 AM","6:46 AM","6:47 AM","6:48 AM","6:49 AM","6:50 AM","6:51 AM","6:52 AM","6:53 AM","6:54 AM","6:55 AM","6:56 AM","6:57 AM","6:58 AM","6:59 AM","7:00 AM","7:01 AM","7:02 AM","7:03 AM","7:04 AM","7:05 AM","7:06 AM","7:07 AM","7:08 AM","7:09 AM","7:10 AM","7:11 AM","7:12 AM","7:13 AM","7:14 AM","7:15 AM","7:16 AM","7:17 AM","7:18 AM","7:19 AM","7:20 AM","7:21 AM","7:22 AM","7:23 AM","7:24 AM","7:25 AM","7:26 AM","7:27 AM","7:28 AM","7:29 AM","7:30 AM","7:31 AM","7:32 AM","7:33 AM","7:34 AM","7:35 AM","7:36 AM","7:37 AM","7:38 AM","7:39 AM","7:40 AM","7:41 AM","7:42 AM","7:43 AM","7:44 AM","7:45 AM","7:46 AM","7:47 AM","7:48 AM","7:49 AM","7:50 AM","7:51 AM","7:52 AM","7:53 AM","7:54 AM","7:55 AM","7:56 AM","7:57 AM","7:58 AM","7:59 AM","8:00 AM","8:01 AM","8:02 AM","8:03 AM","8:04 AM","8:05 AM","8:06 AM","8:07 AM","8:08 AM","8:09 AM","8:10 AM","8:11 AM","8:12 AM","8:13 AM","8:14 AM","8:15 AM","8:16 AM","8:17 AM","8:18 AM","8:19 AM","8:20 AM","8:21 AM","8:22 AM","8:23 AM","8:24 AM","8:25 AM","8:26 AM","8:27 AM","8:28 AM","8:29 AM","8:30 AM","8:31 AM","8:32 AM","8:33 AM","8:34 AM","8:35 AM","8:36 AM","8:37 AM","8:38 AM","8:39 AM","8:40 AM","8:41 AM","8:42 AM","8:43 AM","8:44 AM","8:45 AM","8:46 AM","8:47 AM","8:48 AM","8:49 AM","8:50 AM","8:51 AM","8:52 AM","8:53 AM","8:54 AM","8:55 AM","8:56 AM","8:57 AM","8:58 AM","8:59 AM","9:00 AM","9:01 AM","9:02 AM","9:03 AM","9:04 AM","9:05 AM","9:06 AM","9:07 AM","9:08 AM","9:09 AM","9:10 AM","9:11 AM","9:12 AM","9:13 AM","9:14 AM","9:15 AM","9:16 AM","9:17 AM","9:18 AM","9:19 AM","9:20 AM","9:21 AM","9:22 AM","9:23 AM","9:24 AM","9:25 AM","9:26 AM","9:27 AM","9:28 AM","9:29 AM","9:30 AM","9:31 AM","9:32 AM","9:33 AM","9:34 AM","9:35 AM","9:36 AM","9:37 AM","9:38 AM","9:39 AM","9:40 AM","9:41 AM","9:42 AM","9:43 AM","9:44 AM","9:45 AM","9:46 AM","9:47 AM","9:48 AM","9:49 AM","9:50 AM","9:51 AM","9:52 AM","9:53 AM","9:54 AM","9:55 AM","9:56 AM","9:57 AM","9:58 AM","9:59 AM","10:00 AM","10:01 AM","10:02 AM","10:03 AM","10:04 AM","10:05 AM","10:06 AM","10:07 AM","10:08 AM","10:09 AM","10:10 AM","10:11 AM","10:12 AM","10:13 AM","10:14 AM","10:15 AM","10:16 AM","10:17 AM","10:18 AM","10:19 AM","10:20 AM","10:21 AM","10:22 AM","10:23 AM","10:24 AM","10:25 AM","10:26 AM","10:27 AM","10:28 AM","10:29 AM","10:30 AM","10:31 AM","10:32 AM","10:33 AM","10:34 AM","10:35 AM","10:36 AM","10:37 AM","10:38 AM","10:39 AM","10:40 AM","10:41 AM","10:42 AM","10:43 AM","10:44 AM","10:45 AM","10:46 AM","10:47 AM","10:48 AM","10:49 AM","10:50 AM","10:51 AM","10:52 AM","10:53 AM","10:54 AM","10:55 AM","10:56 AM","10:57 AM","10:58 AM","10:59 AM","11:00 AM","11:01 AM","11:02 AM","11:03 AM","11:04 AM","11:05 AM","11:06 AM","11:07 AM","11:08 AM","11:09 AM","11:10 AM","11:11 AM","11:12 AM","11:13 AM","11:14 AM","11:15 AM","11:16 AM","11:17 AM","11:18 AM","11:19 AM","11:20 AM","11:21 AM","11:22 AM","11:23 AM","11:24 AM","11:25 AM","11:26 AM","11:27 AM","11:28 AM","11:29 AM","11:30 AM","11:31 AM","11:32 AM","11:33 AM","11:34 AM","11:35 AM","11:36 AM","11:37 AM","11:38 AM","11:39 AM","11:40 AM","11:41 AM","11:42 AM","11:43 AM","11:44 AM","11:45 AM","11:46 AM","11:47 AM","11:48 AM","11:49 AM","11:50 AM","11:51 AM","11:52 AM","11:53 AM","11:54 AM","11:55 AM","11:56 AM","11:57 AM","11:58 AM","11:59 AM","12:00 PM","12:01 PM","12:02 PM","12:03 PM","12:04 PM","12:05 PM","12:06 PM","12:07 PM","12:08 PM","12:09 PM","12:10 PM","12:11 PM","12:12 PM","12:13 PM","12:14 PM","12:15 PM","12:16 PM","12:17 PM","12:18 PM","12:19 PM","12:20 PM","12:21 PM","12:22 PM","12:23 PM","12:24 PM","12:25 PM","12:26 PM","12:27 PM","12:28 PM","12:29 PM","12:30 PM","12:31 PM","12:32 PM","12:33 PM","12:34 PM","12:35 PM","12:36 PM","12:37 PM","12:38 PM","12:39 PM","12:40 PM","12:41 PM","12:42 PM","12:43 PM","12:44 PM","12:45 PM","12:46 PM","12:47 PM","12:48 PM","12:49 PM","12:50 PM","12:51 PM","12:52 PM","12:53 PM","12:54 PM","12:55 PM","12:56 PM","12:57 PM","12:58 PM","12:59 PM","1:00 PM","1:01 PM","1:02 PM","1:03 PM","1:04 PM","1:05 PM","1:06 PM","1:07 PM","1:08 PM","1:09 PM","1:10 PM","1:11 PM","1:12 PM","1:13 PM","1:14 PM","1:15 PM","1:16 PM","1:17 PM","1:18 PM","1:19 PM","1:20 PM","1:21 PM","1:22 PM","1:23 PM","1:24 PM","1:25 PM","1:26 PM","1:27 PM","1:28 PM","1:29 PM","1:30 PM","1:31 PM","1:32 PM","1:33 PM","1:34 PM","1:35 PM","1:36 PM","1:37 PM","1:38 PM","1:39 PM","1:40 PM","1:41 PM","1:42 PM","1:43 PM","1:44 PM","1:45 PM","1:46 PM","1:47 PM","1:48 PM","1:49 PM","1:50 PM","1:51 PM","1:52 PM","1:53 PM","1:54 PM","1:55 PM","1:56 PM","1:57 PM","1:58 PM","1:59 PM","2:00 PM","2:01 PM","2:02 PM","2:03 PM","2:04 PM","2:05 PM","2:06 PM","2:07 PM","2:08 PM","2:09 PM","2:10 PM","2:11 PM","2:12 PM","2:13 PM","2:14 PM","2:15 PM","2:16 PM","2:17 PM","2:18 PM","2:19 PM","2:20 PM","2:21 PM","2:22 PM","2:23 PM","2:24 PM","2:25 PM","2:26 PM","2:27 PM","2:28 PM","2:29 PM","2:30 PM","2:31 PM","2:32 PM","2:33 PM","2:34 PM","2:35 PM","2:36 PM","2:37 PM","2:38 PM","2:39 PM","2:40 PM","2:41 PM","2:42 PM","2:43 PM","2:44 PM","2:45 PM","2:46 PM","2:47 PM","2:48 PM","2:49 PM","2:50 PM","2:51 PM","2:52 PM","2:53 PM","2:54 PM","2:55 PM","2:56 PM","2:57 PM","2:58 PM","2:59 PM","3:00 PM","3:01 PM","3:02 PM","3:03 PM","3:04 PM","3:05 PM","3:06 PM","3:07 PM","3:08 PM","3:09 PM","3:10 PM","3:11 PM","3:12 PM","3:13 PM","3:14 PM","3:15 PM","3:16 PM","3:17 PM","3:18 PM","3:19 PM","3:20 PM","3:21 PM","3:22 PM","3:23 PM","3:24 PM","3:25 PM","3:26 PM","3:27 PM","3:28 PM","3:29 PM","3:30 PM","3:31 PM","3:32 PM","3:33 PM","3:34 PM","3:35 PM","3:36 PM","3:37 PM","3:38 PM","3:39 PM","3:40 PM","3:41 PM","3:42 PM","3:43 PM","3:44 PM","3:45 PM","3:46 PM","3:47 PM","3:48 PM","3:49 PM","3:50 PM","3:51 PM","3:52 PM","3:53 PM","3:54 PM","3:55 PM","3:56 PM","3:57 PM","3:58 PM","3:59 PM","4:00 PM","4:01 PM","4:02 PM","4:03 PM","4:04 PM","4:05 PM","4:06 PM","4:07 PM","4:08 PM","4:09 PM","4:10 PM","4:11 PM","4:12 PM","4:13 PM","4:14 PM","4:15 PM","4:16 PM","4:17 PM","4:18 PM","4:19 PM","4:20 PM","4:21 PM","4:22 PM","4:23 PM","4:24 PM","4:25 PM","4:26 PM","4:27 PM","4:28 PM","4:29 PM","4:30 PM","4:31 PM","4:32 PM","4:33 PM","4:34 PM","4:35 PM","4:36 PM","4:37 PM","4:38 PM","4:39 PM","4:40 PM","4:41 PM","4:42 PM","4:43 PM","4:44 PM","4:45 PM","4:46 PM","4:47 PM","4:48 PM","4:49 PM","4:50 PM","4:51 PM","4:52 PM","4:53 PM","4:54 PM","4:55 PM","4:56 PM","4:57 PM","4:58 PM","4:59 PM","5:00 PM","5:01 PM","5:02 PM","5:03 PM","5:04 PM","5:05 PM","5:06 PM","5:07 PM","5:08 PM","5:09 PM","5:10 PM","5:11 PM","5:12 PM","5:13 PM","5:14 PM","5:15 PM","5:16 PM","5:17 PM","5:18 PM","5:19 PM","5:20 PM","5:21 PM","5:22 PM","5:23 PM","5:24 PM","5:25 PM","5:26 PM","5:27 PM","5:28 PM","5:29 PM","5:30 PM","5:31 PM","5:32 PM","5:33 PM","5:34 PM","5:35 PM","5:36 PM","5:37 PM","5:38 PM","5:39 PM","5:40 PM","5:41 PM","5:42 PM","5:43 PM","5:44 PM","5:45 PM","5:46 PM","5:47 PM","5:48 PM","5:49 PM","5:50 PM","5:51 PM","5:52 PM","5:53 PM","5:54 PM","5:55 PM","5:56 PM","5:57 PM","5:58 PM","5:59 PM","6:00 PM","6:01 PM","6:02 PM","6:03 PM","6:04 PM","6:05 PM","6:06 PM","6:07 PM","6:08 PM","6:09 PM","6:10 PM","6:11 PM","6:12 PM","6:13 PM","6:14 PM","6:15 PM","6:16 PM","6:17 PM","6:18 PM","6:19 PM","6:20 PM","6:21 PM","6:22 PM","6:23 PM","6:24 PM","6:25 PM","6:26 PM","6:27 PM","6:28 PM","6:29 PM","6:30 PM","6:31 PM","6:32 PM","6:33 PM","6:34 PM","6:35 PM","6:36 PM","6:37 PM","6:38 PM","6:39 PM","6:40 PM","6:41 PM","6:42 PM","6:43 PM","6:44 PM","6:45 PM","6:46 PM","6:47 PM","6:48 PM","6:49 PM","6:50 PM","6:51 PM","6:52 PM","6:53 PM","6:54 PM","6:55 PM","6:56 PM","6:57 PM","6:58 PM","6:59 PM","7:00 PM","7:01 PM","7:02 PM","7:03 PM","7:04 PM","7:05 PM","7:06 PM","7:07 PM","7:08 PM","7:09 PM","7:10 PM","7:11 PM","7:12 PM","7:13 PM","7:14 PM","7:15 PM","7:16 PM","7:17 PM","7:18 PM","7:19 PM","7:20 PM","7:21 PM","7:22 PM","7:23 PM","7:24 PM","7:25 PM","7:26 PM","7:27 PM","7:28 PM","7:29 PM","7:30 PM","7:31 PM","7:32 PM","7:33 PM","7:34 PM","7:35 PM","7:36 PM","7:37 PM","7:38 PM","7:39 PM","7:40 PM","7:41 PM","7:42 PM","7:43 PM","7:44 PM","7:45 PM","7:46 PM","7:47 PM","7:48 PM","7:49 PM","7:50 PM","7:51 PM","7:52 PM","7:53 PM","7:54 PM","7:55 PM","7:56 PM","7:57 PM","7:58 PM","7:59 PM","8:00 PM","8:01 PM","8:02 PM","8:03 PM","8:04 PM","8:05 PM","8:06 PM","8:07 PM","8:08 PM","8:09 PM","8:10 PM","8:11 PM","8:12 PM","8:13 PM","8:14 PM","8:15 PM","8:16 PM","8:17 PM","8:18 PM","8:19 PM","8:20 PM","8:21 PM","8:22 PM","8:23 PM","8:24 PM","8:25 PM","8:26 PM","8:27 PM","8:28 PM","8:29 PM","8:30 PM","8:31 PM","8:32 PM","8:33 PM","8:34 PM","8:35 PM","8:36 PM","8:37 PM","8:38 PM","8:39 PM","8:40 PM","8:41 PM","8:42 PM","8:43 PM","8:44 PM","8:45 PM","8:46 PM","8:47 PM","8:48 PM","8:49 PM","8:50 PM","8:51 PM","8:52 PM","8:53 PM","8:54 PM","8:55 PM","8:56 PM","8:57 PM","8:58 PM","8:59 PM","9:00 PM","9:01 PM","9:02 PM","9:03 PM","9:04 PM","9:05 PM","9:06 PM","9:07 PM","9:08 PM","9:09 PM","9:10 PM","9:11 PM","9:12 PM","9:13 PM","9:14 PM","9:15 PM","9:16 PM","9:17 PM","9:18 PM","9:19 PM","9:20 PM","9:21 PM","9:22 PM","9:23 PM","9:24 PM","9:25 PM","9:26 PM","9:27 PM","9:28 PM","9:29 PM","9:30 PM","9:31 PM","9:32 PM","9:33 PM","9:34 PM","9:35 PM","9:36 PM","9:37 PM","9:38 PM","9:39 PM","9:40 PM","9:41 PM","9:42 PM","9:43 PM","9:44 PM","9:45 PM","9:46 PM","9:47 PM","9:48 PM","9:49 PM","9:50 PM","9:51 PM","9:52 PM","9:53 PM","9:54 PM","9:55 PM","9:56 PM","9:57 PM","9:58 PM","9:59 PM","10:00 PM","10:01 PM","10:02 PM","10:03 PM","10:04 PM","10:05 PM","10:06 PM","10:07 PM","10:08 PM","10:09 PM","10:10 PM","10:11 PM","10:12 PM","10:13 PM","10:14 PM","10:15 PM","10:16 PM","10:17 PM","10:18 PM","10:19 PM","10:20 PM","10:21 PM","10:22 PM","10:23 PM","10:24 PM","10:25 PM","10:26 PM","10:27 PM","10:28 PM","10:29 PM","10:30 PM","10:31 PM","10:32 PM","10:33 PM","10:34 PM","10:35 PM","10:36 PM","10:37 PM","10:38 PM","10:39 PM","10:40 PM","10:41 PM","10:42 PM","10:43 PM","10:44 PM","10:45 PM","10:46 PM","10:47 PM","10:48 PM","10:49 PM","10:50 PM","10:51 PM","10:52 PM","10:53 PM","10:54 PM","10:55 PM","10:56 PM","10:57 PM","10:58 PM","10:59 PM","11:00 PM","11:01 PM","11:02 PM","11:03 PM","11:04 PM","11:05 PM","11:06 PM","11:07 PM","11:08 PM","11:09 PM","11:10 PM","11:11 PM","11:12 PM","11:13 PM","11:14 PM","11:15 PM","11:16 PM","11:17 PM","11:18 PM","11:19 PM","11:20 PM","11:21 PM","11:22 PM","11:23 PM","11:24 PM","11:25 PM","11:26 PM","11:27 PM","11:28 PM","11:29 PM","11:30 PM","11:31 PM","11:32 PM","11:33 PM","11:34 PM","11:35 PM","11:36 PM","11:37 PM","11:38 PM","11:39 PM","11:40 PM","11:41 PM","11:42 PM","11:43 PM","11:44 PM","11:45 PM","11:46 PM","11:47 PM","11:48 PM","11:49 PM","11:50 PM","11:51 PM","11:52 PM","11:53 PM","11:54 PM","11:55 PM","11:56 PM","11:57 PM","11:58 PM","11:59 PM"];
```

Comment: Its nearly impossible to use IE11 dev-tools anyway)

Comment: I don't see why someone down-voted, this seems like a strong question to me.

Comment: You can try disabling all add-ons and opening a new IE window, as suggested in the last post of [this discussion](https://forums.asp.net/t/2015022.aspx?Is+there+any+other+development+tool+F12+available+for+IE+11+x+) on a Microsoft forum.

Comment: basically IE developer tools don't work great. It's a pretty well documented issue.

Comment: If the solution can applicable to you? Increment time by 5 Mins so that total item count is 288 only...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1275/

Answer (score 3):

As to why this occurs, I can only speculate. It is possible that the IE Dev Tools limit the memory allocated to running either certain third-party frameworks or scripting in general. I assume it is memory related because of the large number of repeated tasks. Either that or AngularJS isn't optimized for IE11 yet.

As to a fix for the problem, I would consider breaking this into two or three fields: hours and minutes (and possibly am/pm). This may have not been the option that you're looking for, but if it would work with your program I would definitely recommend it. Here are two reasons:

1. **User interface**: the user does not want to scroll through 1,440 options, trust me. It's tedious and time consuming, especially on a mobile device. *Imagine all those times that you have to scroll through a few hundred countries on a checkout page because the programmer couldn't detect the user's location and place it at the top of the field.* Having multiple fields, hour + minute +am/pm, reduces the number of options from 1,440 to 12, 60, and 2 respectively. You'll notice that this method is used for entering a time all over the web.
2. **Less resources**: instead of reiterating 1,440 times (for each value in the array), you will reiterate 74 times (12+60+2). That is a 2000% reduction in resources.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. If there is no solution I will consider this.

Comment: Good luck, I know this wasn't what you were looking for, but I hope it helps if you need it.

Comment: Did you get a chance to test this

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem for the project itself, but if you're going to improve performance: use infinite/partial load in your selector (show only ~30, by scrolling remove/add chunks) or change it to a clock widget (or even customizable select-widget: check "Options With Async Search" in https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select ).

```
<select> - element is a part of OS representation
```

That's why you're not able to customize it full enough. Win + IE hardly can process a big scope of elements (for the most JS frameworks you'll be able to track issues with performance under Internet Explorer)

Answer (score 0):

ngRepeat was a lot faster than ngOptions (~3 seconds vs ~10, respectively) for dropdown with ~500 items, in your case you have 1440 items..

Answer (score 0):

```
If the below solution can be applicable to you? 

Then Increment time by 5 Mins, So that total item count is 288 only.
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/1275/)